# How to hide softkeyboard when it is on radioButton

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am working on an application where I am creating layout dynamically. 
I'm stuck with the problem that I want to hide the keyboard when there is a RadioButton. I have 5 consecutive edit text boxes (Generated Dynamically). After that the RadioButton part starts. I Want to hide the keyboard when there are radio Buttons and show it again when edit text appears.

I tried this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if you call this method in an 'onClick()'  it will forcibly close the keyboard.

private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null && getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditTextHere.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Working..I am generating Edit texts in onPostExecute method of the  AsynTask.